# How to detect a desktop application hanging

Tags: scripting, process-management

I want to write a script that will detect whether a particular desktop application is responding and kill it. Is this possible?

I know I've seen the GNOME desktop put up a "Application is not responding" dialog, and I figure it sends some sort of signal to the window and waits a certain amount of time for a response. If there's a way to do something like that, I'd appreciate some details. Thank you!

(This is on xfce, if it matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can comment on Gnome's "Application is not responding" dialog, but not directly answer your question.

It seems that both Metacity and Mutter use [meta_display_ping_window()](http://code.metager.de/source/s?refs=meta_display_ping_window&project=gnome) function to determine the status of a window (read the doc comment in `display.c`).

The default timeout `PING_TIMEOUT_DELAY` is 5 s. Ping-timeout and response are handled internally by the window manager and at a glance I don't see a simple method to watch this ping-pong party from outside.

Comment: Sometimes "there is no solution" is the best answer.  Thanks.